# Listview not inflating with json

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

i have to inflate listview with the Json data with parameters . But it gives error 2.onErrorResponse: MainActivity . I checked multiple times with String Request and Json Request but none of them is working... Please Help!!!

```
      JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();


                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);


                            title_array.add(obj.getString("amount").toString());
                            notice_array.add(obj.getString("payment_id").toString());
                            title1_array.add(obj.getString("invoice_id").toString());
                            notice1_array.add(obj.getString("payment_date").toString());
                            notice2_array.add(obj.getString("movieName").toString());
                            notice3_array.add(obj.getString("source").toString());

                            adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(Transaction.this, title_array, notice_array,title1_array,notice1_array,notice2_array,notice3_array);

                            list.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }


                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id", user_id);
            params.put("user_type", User_type);

            return params;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    requestQueue.add(movieReq);
```

Comment: Why do you have a try statement inside of a for loop? Also, why are you setting the adapter on every loop? It looks like you're trying to add each result to the adapter, so first populate a List<whatever> then add the list to the adapter. If you're using an ArrayAdapter, this is easy.

Comment: its gives error if i doesn't use try catch block.. i also seprate the adapter and declare in end but no luck :/

Comment: You need to declare the adapter as a class property rather than a method property, so that the scope of access for the property is global within the class. Put the try/catch around the for loop. Besides, you're instantiating a new adapter `response.length` times, so it won't work. Look up how to use ArrayAdapter.

Comment: i use base adapter !!! and it works fine with the Apache library now i want to just convert it into volley!!! I think the issue is in passing params ...

Comment: You're instantiating the adapter `response.length` times, which could be `n` times, as well as attaching it to the list the same number of times. This is incredibly inefficient, cpu and memory consuming.

Comment: so what i do? please help with some code!!!

Comment: Android docs have a tutorial on how to use ArrayAdapter